# Linux system command not working in Perl script via crontab

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I have added a script in crontab for every 30 minutes. The line goes as follows:

```
  */30 * * * * root perl /root/perl.pl
```

The above script has a execution of system command 'top' and it gets printed in a log file.

If I run it manually it runs fine. But while running it via crontab, it does not show up the desired results. Please can somebody help me with this. Thank you.

---

The command in the above perl script is:

```
 $top = `sudo top`;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

I changed my command from sudo to visudo. But still the problem remains.

Comment: What is the `roor` command and why is it in front of `perl`?

Comment: root is to run the script as superuser..Is that affecting?

Comment: When a script works on the command line but fails when run from crontab, it's almost always the environment.  Either you've got an environment variable that's not set in your crontab, or you're expecting it to start in a different directory.

Comment: @cjm - Please can you elaborate or atleast give me some hint how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Dump `%ENV` and see what's different.

Comment: @deep PATH might be different when executed as a cronjob (if so, you may need to specify full path to `perl`). Check your cron logs for errors.

Comment: I have edited the SHELL, PATH, HOME variables in /etc/crontab as per the environment variables. But still no luck. @cjm Any specific steps to be followed will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me the first thing you should do is capture the error messages it gives!!!

Comment: @ikegami I have given the error message below. I hope you do not mind. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path in cron (and use `which perl` to find the full path):

```
*/30 * * * * root /usr/bin/perl /root/perl.pl
```

OR better yet, make the script executable using `chmod +x`, and add the interpreter to the beginning of the script `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` and call it directly from cron

```
*/30 * * * * root /root/perl.pl
```

Also if there is a problem in the perl script, you could output the result from cron like this

```
*/30 * * * * root /root/perl.pl > /tmp/myscript.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the `requiretty` setting with regard to visudo. Look for a line that reads `Defaults  requiretty`. You could try commenting it out, but you will be sacrificing some security. See `man sudoers`.

You could also try running `top` in batch mode with one iteration:

```
$top = `sudo top -bn1`;
```

Batch mode option is for sending output to other programs.